# How to fill a 2D array with random non duplicate numbers in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to fill my 2D array with random numbers without duplicates. I currently have it filed with random numbers within the correct range, but I just cant think of a solution to have non duplicates. How could i do this using very basic java methods? I have not yet learned anything such as arraylists, or anything like that, only the very basic methods.

Comment: Show the code you have so far, otherwise it's too broad, too many ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Given a MxN integer array, you could fill the array with numbers from 1 to M*N using two for-loops, and then swap them using the Fisher-Yates algorithm.

**EDIT:**
I changed the algorithm so that it now does not create a new integer-array every time the algorithm is called. It uses one loop, and calculates m, n, i j from a random value and the iterating varaible l. Assuming the given array is not null, rectangular and at least 1x0 in size:

```
public static void fillRandomlyUniqe(int[][] a) {
    /*
    fill up the array with incrementing values
    if the values should start at another value, change here
    */
    int value = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            a[i][j] = value++;
    }

    // swap them using Fisher-Yates algorithm
    Random r = new Random();
    int max = a.length * a[0].length;
    for (int l = max - 1; l > 0; l--) {

        //calculate a two dimensional index from random number
        int index = r.nextInt(l + 1);
        int m = index % a.length;
        int n = index / a.length;

        //calculate two dimensional index from the iterating value
        int i = l % a.length;
        int j = l / a.length;

        int temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[m][n];
        a[m][n] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fisher-Yates is a one-dimensional shuffle.  This attempt to modify it to a two-dimensional array resulted in less randomness than you intended!  An element for row i=0 is only exchanged with elements in row m=0, and column j=0 is only exchanged with column n=0.  It is possible that some element from i>0,j>0 will get swapped into the first row/column, but there will always be a bias in the resulting shuffling.  Flatten the array into a vector, shuffle, then reshape back to NxM is the proper technique.

Comment: I have corrected the algorithm, now itswaps on a one dimensional array, and then copy it into the two dimensional one

Comment: Much better.  I'd replace `values[i * a[0].length + j]` with `values[k++]`, but that is personal preference.

Comment: I changed it again to not create a integer array every time called

Answer (score -1):

If your 2D array is NxM, and you want numbers from (say) 1 to NxM randomly placed in your 2D array, the simplest is to create an array/list with the numbers from 1 to NxM, shuffle it, then fill in your 2D array sequentially from the shuffled data.  You are guaranteed to not have any duplicates because the original non-shuffled data is full of unique values.

```
List<Integer> data = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, M * N).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(data);
Iterator<Integer> iter = data.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        array[i][j] = iter.next();
    }
}
```

There is probably a way to do the second half with the stream API too, but it escapes me at the moment.

Comment: I know you asked for a method without `ArrayList`, streams, iterators, etc., but the technique would be the same.  If you can wrap your head around what this code does, writing the equivalent "basic method" implementation should be easy.

Comment: But what if the reason he asked for a method without `ArrayList`s, streams, etc is because he hasn't yet learned how those advanced features work and thus won't be able to understand your code.

Comment: @ppperry - Then two points: 1) If someone without a similar limitation searches for this post's title, this answer would be useful to them.  2) StackOverflow is not a homework writing service.  If the OP had shown an attempt to solve the problem, we could provide more specific help. Since they did not, I provided a solution, in words, that would give them a good start at solving the problem.  The code provides a second "wording" of the same solution -- but in a fashion that prevents them from copying it verbatim without understanding it, as it violates their own restriction.